# std::is_same_v<> returns false for enum declared with type?

Tags: c++, enums

Below is some code I am testing following the [example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type) for std::underlying_type. I'm expecting it to output "true", but instead it outputs "false":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum class Color: int
{
  Red,
  Blue
};

int main()
{
  constexpr bool match = std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type<Color>, int>;

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << match << std::endl;
}
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: `std::underlying_type_t<Color>` or `std::underlying_type<Color>::type`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::underlying_type` is a class with a member type alias `type` which encodes the actual underlying type.

If you want that type, you need to ask for it explicitly:

```
constexpr bool match = std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type_t<Color>, int>;
                                                      //  ^^
```

or

```
constexpr bool match = std::is_same_v<std::underlying_type<Color>::type, int>;
                                                             //  ^^^^^^
```

Comment: ... Thank you for your quick answer.